# is there any Solution on combining two column data in one array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a problem which i want to display **Firstname** and **Lastname** column from my database as a one data using the array.
BTW I am new to array code. I tried to browse any similar result of this but cant come up with the solution. Anything that will help me is highly appreciated. Thanks.

this is my current code:

```
// DB table to use
$table = 'tbl_employee';

// Table's primary key
$primaryKey = 'id_ref';

// Array of database columns which should be read and sent back to DataTables.
// The `db` parameter represents the column name in the database, while the `dt`
// parameter represents the DataTables column identifier. In this case simple
// indexes

$columns = array(
    array( 'db' => 'emp_id_no', 'dt' => 0 ),

    //this is my problem!! I want to combine this two different column.
    array( 'db' => 'emp_lname' . "" .'db' => 'emp_fname', 'dt' => 1 ),


    array( 'db' => 'emp_dep', 'dt' => 2 ),
    array( 'db' => 'emp_job_name',  'dt' => 3 ),
    array( 'db' => 'emp_status',  'dt' => 4 ),


);
```

Comment: Hi! thanks for showing me that. Can someone help me on the given problem above. In additional info, I use that for server processing in php event. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Without using an array to concatenate `emp_lname` and `emp_fname` you can use a sql query so that it will speed up the process and increase the understandability of your code.

```
 $fullName = SELECT 
    emp_fname,
    emp_lname,
    CONCAT(emp_fname, ' ', emp_lname) full_name
FROM 
    tbl_employee
ORDER BY 
    full_name;
```

What I'm trying to do here is , get the `emp_fname` and `emp_lname` from the table and then assign it to a variable called `fullName`.so the you can use this variable inside the array instead of concatinating the columns inside the array.

You can use this link for extra reference on **concat in sql server** :  http://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-string-functions/sql-server-concat-function/

Hope this will help you to resolve your issue.